# JsonObject doesn't fill table correctly

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to read and parse Json file;

```
JSONArray hops = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("hops");
if (hops != null) {
    Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = hops.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject itr = iterator.next();

        rtt += (double) itr.get("rtt");
        reply_ttl += (double) itr.get("reply_rtt");
        probe_ttl += (long) itr.get("probe_ttl");
    }
    rtt = rtt / (hopCount * 2);
    reply_ttl = (int) (reply_ttl / hopCount);
    probe_ttl = (int) (probe_ttl / hopCount);               
}
```

I can take `rtt` correctly but `NullPointerException` returns for `reply_ttl` and `probe_ttl` values. While debugging I can see that `itr` includes all attributes which the file has;

```
{
  "icmp_type": 11,
  "probe_id": 1,
  "icmp_q_ipl": 44,
  "reply_tos": 192,
  "reply_ipid": 9760,
  "icmp_q_ttl": 1,
  "rtt": 0.264,
  "reply_size": 56,
  "probe_size": 44,
  "icmp_code": 0,
  "icmp_q_tos": 0,
  "addr": "193.1.31.125",
  "probe_ttl": 1,
  "reply_ttl": 255
}
```

But when I look at the HashMap values for `itr`, only 9 attributes are put into the table. Why all Json nodes are not put into the table?

Comment: You need to specify the full JSON structure for checking the issue here. As @Greg Zero mentioned "reply_rtt" is not there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be a typo here:

```
reply_ttl += (double) itr.get("reply_rtt");
```

You are checking for the key "reply_rtt", but in the spec at the bottom, there is no key by that name. Is this where the exception is thrown?

If that doesn't solve your problem, would you be able to add more context to your question? Is this the org.json library? It would be helpful to see the contents of `jsonObject` where the "hops" object is found, and to see how the other variables are declared.

About the missing values, it's possible that this JSON library does not put null values into its internal HashMap. So, for example, if you read the string `"{\"key\":null}"` you might just get an empty map.